# Why am I getting this result from recursive query in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to write a prolog predicate that generates a horizontal line using SWI-Prolog 7. I started with a simple generator referenced here: [Simple Prolog generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109558/simple-prolog-generator)

In playing around, I came up with a result I don't understand. If I create these rules (hline is intended to take two x coordinates (X and A) and a single Y coordinate Y, and generate the X and Y coordinates of a horizontal line in S and T:

```
gen(Cur, Top, Cur) :- =<(Cur, Top). 
gen(Cur, Top, Next):- =<(Cur, Top), is(Cur1, +(Cur, 1)), gen(Cur1, Top, Next).
hline(X,A,Y,S,T) :- gen(X,A,S), T is Y.
```

When I run this query:

```
hline(0,5,0,X,Y).
```

I get these results.  The first one is the one I don't understand:

```
X = Y, Y = 0
X = 1,
Y = 0
X = 2,
Y = 0
X = 3,
Y = 0
X = 4,
Y = 0
X = 5,
Y = 0
```

Can someone explain why the first result is X=Y, Y=0?  I can't see anywhere that X and Y are even in the same clause through unification or reduction...

Comment: These simply refer to the same number. If you write `X = 0, Y = 0`, then nowhere you explicitly set `X = Y`, but still, swi-Prolog for example reports it as `X = Y, Y = 0`. Since both refer to the `0` constant.

Comment: `X=Y, Y=0` is the same as `X = 0, Y = 0`. BTW, it would be clearer to write `Cur =< Top` instead of `=<(Cur, Top)` and `Cur1 is Cur + 1` instead of `is(Cur1, +(Cur, 1))`. Prolog allows the more readable notation for operators. I see you wrote `T is Y` and not `is(T, Y)`. In that particular case you could also just use unification: `hline(X,A,Y,S,Y) :- gen(X,A,S).`

Comment: OK, that was too easy. Thanks guys!